# Python Numpy pct_change in reverse

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using numpy to get the change between datapoints over some period.

```py
   df["ema_10_diff"] = df["mid_price"].pct_change(10 * 60)
```

Now what I need to do is revert this back to the cumulative change over time. If the period was set to the standard period = 1. Then I would just write this:

```py
   df["ema_10_diff_reconstructed"] = (df["ema_10_diff"] + 1).cumprod()
```

But because the period is 10 * 60 I cannot do this and there is no period parameter for cumprod. Does anyone know how to reconstruct the original values. I know it will start at 1 and not really be the original values but it will show the cumulative percentage changed.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: that's not a reproducible example Erik! Please include all the steps (in your question) to create the df

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I need to prepend my percent changed list with period amount of original values to get back to the original.

```py
# Get percent difference
df["ema_10_diff"] = df["mid_price"].pct_change(10 * 60) + 1

# Prepend data with original values of length: period
x = (
        df["mid_price"][: 10 * 60]
        .append(df["ema_10_diff"], ignore_index=True)
    )

# Function to get the cumulative product with period in between.
def cumprod_period(series: pd.Series, period=1) -> pd.Series:
    output = list(series[:period])
    series_length = len(series)
    for i in range(period, series_length):
        current_item = series[i]
        previous_item = output[-period]
        prod = current_item * previous_item

        output.append(prod)

    return pd.Series(output)

# Result is same as df['mid_price']
df["reconstructed_mid_price"] = cumprod_period(x, 10 * 60)
```

Here is the unit test I wrote to check if it works:

```py
def test_cumprod_period():
    """Tests if the function works"""
    input = [10, 20, 80, 20, 20, 10]

    period = 2

    # Prepended the first 2 values of the original list to the percentage 
    changed.
    pct_change = pd.Series([10, 20, 8.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.5])

    output = cumprod_period(pct_change, period)

    assert list(output) == input, f"{list(output)} != {input}"
```

Comment: well done! Now include a reproducible example so it's useful for anyone else experiencing the same problem :-)

Comment: And would also allow others to potentially provide alternative answers